# Find programmatically if under C++ or C++/CLI

Tags: compilation, c++-cli

I would like my C++/CLI headers to compile even when under another platform. Of course I am not expecting to compile them but just ignore them.

Would this be appropriate ? (_MSC_VER)

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

    using namespace System;

        namespace ENMFP {

            public ref struct Data {
            };
        }

#endif
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `__cplusplus_cli` predefined macro documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli

using namespace System;

namespace ENMFP
{
    public ref struct Data
    {
        // ...
    };
}

#endif  // __cplusplus_cli
```

Comment: Sorry but I talked too fast, it didn't work, however _MANAGED works.

Comment: @Aybe, that's strange, both macros are supposed to be defined if the `/clr` option is specified. Are you perchance using `/clr:oldSyntax`? In that case, you're targeting Managed C++, not C++/CLI :)

Comment: It is /clr, I think it is C++/CLI since I am on VS2010 but you will tell me, actually it is my first project in C++

Comment: `/clr` is C++/CLI indeed, but in that case `__cplusplus_cli` should also be defined... I cannot explain why it isn't (but `_MANAGED` is) in your case.

Comment: ok I understand now, it is not shown in Intellisense nor I can navigate to it but it exists, I checked with #ifdef __cplusplus_cli #pragma message("cli")

Comment: This doesn't work. If used, it will still be "true" even if the file using this ifdef was included as native header.