# What's the difference between the macros _MANAGED and _cplusplus_cli?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

The [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (even back in 2005) state for both:

- `_MANAGED` : Defined to be `1` when `/clr` is specified.
- `__cplusplus_cli`: Defined when compiling with `/clr`, `/clr:pure`, or `/clr:safe`. (...)

So if I'm compiling a C++/CLI module and need to check, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976274/321013):

> both macros are supposed to be defined if the /clr option is
>   specified. Are you perchance using /clr:oldSyntax? In that case,
>   you're targeting Managed C++, not C++/CLI

And indeed, when looking at the [2003 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) there is only `_MANAGED` and there is no [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) there yet.

To answer *which one should I use*, I'd say it doesn't really matter unless you need to differentiate between `oldSyntax` and CLI.